# How to change values from character to number using if and for statement?

Tags: r

I am handling a microarray data.

I have two tables, one is pathway and gene set table (I will call it as A table)
and the other is microarray table (Lets say it B)

I need to change gene symbols(characters) to expression value(numbers) in A table according to each expression value of gene symbols in B

Tables look like followings

```
A table                                            B table
Pathway   v1    v2   ...v249 v250                 Gene      Value         
   1       A    E        NA   NA                   E        1000
   2       B    A        Z    I                    A         500
   3       C    G        X    NA                   G         200
   4       D    K        P    NA                   B         300
                                                   P          10
                                                   Z          20
```

I want to change A table like following way

```
   A table                            
Pathway   v1       v2   ...    v249 v250      
   1       500    1000         NA    NA 
   2       300    500          20    NA
   3       NA     200          NA    NA
   4       NA     NA           10    NA
```

If there are no matched gene symbols, they should be replaced with 'NA'

Comment: Are you looking for `?merge` ?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is not function that I want. Each pathway has approximately 250 columns(i.e gene symbols).

Comment: I made my question more precise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can also do this using `base R`.  We convert the subset of 'A' (i.e. except the 'Pathway' column) to `matrix`, `match` with 'Gene' from 'B', the numeric index obtained can be used to populate the corresponding 'Value' column, and assign the output back.

```
A1 <- A
A1[-1] <- B$Value[match(as.matrix(A[-1]), B$Gene)]
A1
#  Pathway  v1   v2
#1       1 500 1000
#2       2 300  500
#3       3  NA  200
#4       4  NA   NA
```

NOTE: Datasets from @DavidArenburg's post.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest, first melting, then merging, the dcasting back. This will work for any number of columns in the `A` data set. I will be using the latest `data.table` version on CRAN for this (v 1.9.6+)

```
library(data.table) # V 1.9.6+
res <- melt(setDT(A), id = "Pathway")[setDT(B), Value := i.Value, on = c(value = "Gene")]
dcast(res, Pathway ~ variable, value.var = "Value")
#    Pathway  v1   v2
# 1:       1 500 1000
# 2:       2 300  500
# 3:       3  NA  200
# 4:       4  NA   NA
```

---

Or similarly using Hadleyverse

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
A %>%
  gather(res, Gene, -Pathway) %>%
  left_join(., B, by = "Gene") %>%
  select(-Gene) %>%
  spread(res, Value)
#   Pathway  v1   v2
# 1       1 500 1000
# 2       2 300  500
# 3       3  NA  200
# 4       4  NA   NA
```

---

**Data**

```
A <- structure(list(Pathway = 1:4, v1 = structure(1:4, .Label = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D"), class = "factor"), v2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L, 
4L), .Label = c("A", "E", "G", "K"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Pathway", 
"v1", "v2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

B <- structure(list(Gene = structure(c(3L, 1L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("A", 
"B", "E", "G"), class = "factor"), Value = c(1000L, 500L, 200L, 
300L)), .Names = c("Gene", "Value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: Thank you. It helps me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This can be done most easily using a lookup table, which is in essence a vector with associated names in R:

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(v1 = sample(LETTERS[1:8], 100, replace = TRUE),
                v2 = sample(LETTERS[1:8], 100, replace = TRUE),
                v3 = sample(LETTERS[1:8], 100, replace = TRUE),
                v4 = sample(LETTERS[1:8], 100, replace = TRUE))
lut = runif(6)
names(lut) = LETTERS[1:6]

replace_fun = function(vec) lut[vec]    
df %>% mutate_each(funs(replace_fun), v1:v4)
           a         b
1 0.97821935 0.8584000
2         NA        NA
3 0.56299342 0.9782194
4 0.85840001 0.8584000
5 0.97821935 0.8584000
6 0.06881867 0.9782194
```

Essentially, the name of each element is the letter in `df` and `lut[letter]` looks up which value belongs to that letter. By using `lut[vec]`, we put the entire vector containing letters into the lookup table, which translates the entire vector to the corresponding number.

The `%>%` and `mutate_each` are functions from `dplyr`, which I use to practically perform the replacement on the example data.

Comment: @DavidArenburg It is, `mutate_each` can be used to deal with many columns at once. I expanded the answer to show how to easily apply to multiple columns, `v1:v4` in this case.